# Inject colors in graphs generated by gnuplot in term dumb plot mode

Tags: shell, colors, gnuplot

I use `gnuplot` in *dumb plot mode* (plot directly in terminal) to build monitoring tools in command line. I would like to add colors to my graphs.

Here is a simple view:

```
> gnuplot5 -e "set term dumb 70 20; plot 'file1' pt '@'"

100 +-+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------+-@
    +         +         +         +         +         +         +
 90 +-+                                         'file1'    @  +-+
 80 +-+                                     @                 +-+
    |                                                           |
 70 +-+                                @                      +-+
    |                                                           |
 60 +-+                           @                           +-+
 50 +-+                      @                                +-+
    |                                                           |
 40 +-+                 @                                     +-+
    |                                                           |
 30 +-+            @                                          +-+
 20 +-+       @                                               +-+
    +         +         +         +         +         +         +
 10 +-+--@----+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------+-+
    0         10        20        30        40        50        60
```

with file1:

```
5 10
10 20
15 30
20 40
25 50
30 60
35 70
40 80
50 90
60 100
```

**My attempt to add colors:**

```
> gnuplot5 -e "set term dumb 70 20; plot 'file1' pt '@'" |
           sed 's|@|\\\033[31m@\\\033[0m|g' | cat -v

100 +-+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------+-\@33[31m@\@33[0m
    +         +         +         +         +         +         +
 90 +-+                                         'file1'    \@33[31m@\@33[0m  +-+
 80 +-+                                     \@33[31m@\@33[0m                 +-+
    |                                                           |
 70 +-+                                \@33[31m@\@33[0m                      +-+
    |                                                           |
 60 +-+                           \@33[31m@\@33[0m                           +-+
 50 +-+                      \@33[31m@\@33[0m                                +-+
    |                                                           |
 40 +-+                 \@33[31m@\@33[0m                                     +-+
    |                                                           |
 30 +-+            \@33[31m@\@33[0m                                          +-+
 20 +-+       \@33[31m@\@33[0m                                               +-+
    +         +         +         +         +         +         +
 10 +-+--\@33[31m@\@33[0m----+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------+-+
    0         10        20        30        40        50        60
```

Comment: Try the `caca` terminal for that which is available with version 5.0, but requires libcaca, see https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/feature-requests/346/

Comment: thx, that's neat. The problem is I don't want to make the script depend on other libs. Since I would like to run it on a cluster, the less dependencies the better. How can I inject colors with `sed` or another common tool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Use `grep --colors=always <pattern>`, it uses grep default color highlighting.

```
> gnuplot5 -e "set term dumb 70 20; plot 'file1' pt '@'" |
           grep --color=always '@'
```

**Solution 2**

Use `colout <pattern> <color>`. It has the ability to select the color but a python library has to be installed (`pip install colout`).

```
> gnuplot5 -e "set term dumb 70 20; plot 'file1' pt '@'" | colout '@' green
```

Comment: Another great solution would be https://github.com/paoloantinori/hhighlighter . Uses just ack.